# _SECURE_SCL_THROWS not supported in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, deprecated

I am upgrading projects at work from vs2010 to vs2012 (toolset 10.0 to toolset 11.0).

I have the following macro:

`#define _SECURE_SCL_THROWS 1`

Originally I had removed this (commented it out) to get the project to build since this will throw the error

`error c1189: _secure_scl_throws removed from vs2012`

However, my project manager is really against this and feels this exception catch is crucial to our product's integrity.

I was wondering if there was anyone out there who had encountered this error and had found a replacement for it or a workaround to keep it in the project (I seriously doubt the latter since it has been removed).

NOTE: not sure if this helps but this comment is directly above the macro describing what it does (I'm fairly new to the job and don't understand it that well myself).

```
`//Defines whether incorrect use of Checked Iterators causes an 
// exception or a program termination. If defined as 1, an out 
// of range iterator use causes an exception at runtime. If defined
// as 0, the program is terminated by calling invalid_parameter. 
// The default value for _SECURE_SCL_THROWS is 0, meaning the 
// program will be terminated by default.`
```

Comment: I didn't suspect there was a workaround I was looking more for a replacement but researching the removal of this seems to imply it wasn't a secure method to begin with.

Comment: MS themselves clearly and specifically state that *_SECURE_SCL_THROWS is deprecated. We strongly discourage its use, and recommend that you use more direct defensive programming techniques to ensure that you are passing valid input.* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa985973(v=vs.100).aspx) I'd go back to your manager with this information and hopefully he'll get it.

Comment: He does understand that, we both researched it. He would just prefer the application throw an exception rather than crash for iterator checks. By replacement, I meant another way to handle this. MS discouraged the use since attackers would be able to continue to "probe" your code when an exception is thrown. I'm not entirely sure what this does but my understanding of it kind of implies multiple try-catch statements could be used for the STL containers. But that may be very time consuming.. Maybe I can convince him that terminating the project is for the best...